# Google Sheets API not accepting my API Key

Tags: authorization, google-sheets-api

I generated an API key through Google Developer's Console.  I am trying to read data from a Google Sheet.

However when I do a GET request using the following link:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1nUeRttOMn--b46Vt7FIlU_eoOqvvuOyukAEg2L_UGQQ/values/A1%3AF500?key={abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789}`
```

I get the error message:

> API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.

Full error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My API Key is valid.  How can I resolve the error?  I plan to make the API call via Alteryx.

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward. You're using an invalid API key. What is the type of the key? is it Other or for Web? Try to unrestrict it for now. Also remove the '{}'

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same error. The Key was valid and I even changed the keys but it was not working.

Here's what I did,

Before the error, it looked like this...

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/PUT YOUR SHEET ID HERE/values/Sheet1?valueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE&key=PUT YOUR API KEY HERE/HTTP/1.1`

Then I removed the last bit and got the valid response.

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/PUT YOUR SHEET ID HERE/values/Sheet1?valueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE&key=PUT YOUR API KEY HERE`

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL:

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/PUT YOUR SHEET ID HERE/values/PUT YOUR SHEET NAME HERE (sheet name not spreadsheet name)?key=PUT YOUR API KEY HERE`